# Excel conditional ranking with duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to rank some data within their subgroups. Currently I have ***Rank*** as below by using:

=IF(B2<>"",COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$800,A2,$B$2:$B$800,"<"&B2)+1,"")

It skips blank, however, it does rank duplicate by skipping rank numbers.

How can I get the ***Desired Rank (1)*** and ***(2)***? Please note there are bland cells and ranking should be related to SubGroup (i.e. to rank numbers in RED and rank numbers in BLUE separately by using only one formula). Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you don't want to use the `RANK` function.

I did and I used the following Defined Names:

```
SubGroup    =Sheet1!$A$2:$A$800
Values      =Sheet1!$B$2:$B$800
```

Since the table is sorted by SubGroup, I was able to use the `OFFSET` function with the *height* parameter to return only the relevant Values for each Subgroup.

**RANK**

```
=IF(B2="","",RANK(B2,OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A2,SubGroup,0),1,COUNTIF(SubGroup,A2)),1))
```

**UNIQUE RANK**

```
=IF(B2="","",RANK(B2,OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A2,SubGroup,0),1,COUNTIF(SubGroup,A2)),1)+COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)-1)
```

**DENSE RANK**

```
=IF(B2="","",SUMPRODUCT( (FREQUENCY(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A2,SubGroup,0),1,COUNTIF(SubGroup,A2)), OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A2,SubGroup,0),1,COUNTIF(SubGroup,A2))) > 0) * (B2 >= OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A2,SubGroup,0),1,1+COUNTIF(SubGroup,A2))) ))
```

Note that the final term in the DENSE RANK formula has one additional element than would be returned by the `COUNTIF(SubGroup,A2)` formula.

[image]

Comment: I worked a similar solution to your method. But it's really messy. Yours works beautifully! Thanks a lot for your time and help @Ron Rosenfeld  :)

Comment: For Dense Rank, i got #AN/A error, modified the last part of the formula from 1,1+COUNTIF(SubGroup,A2))) )) to 1,COUNTIF(SubGroup,A2))) )). It worked. Much appreciated!

Comment: @C.C There must be something different about your setup than what I have presented.  If I omit the `1+`, I get the `#NA` error.  Did you perhaps erroneously include the column label row in your ranges?